# Vite Vue3 place multiple ".env" files in a folder

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, dotenv

I have 11 .env files for testing and other reasons.

Is there way I can put them in a folder and use them from there?

Such as:

- /root

  - env-container

    - .env-test1
    - .env-test2
    - .env-test3

Comment: You can just put them in the same folder. Whenever you want to use one, copy and paste the content of it to the `.env` file

Comment: @Duannx Thanks. I am using them all the time so I need to import them somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure the location of the `.env` files with the [`envDir` config](https://vitejs.dev/config/#envdir):

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  envDir: './root/env-container',
})
```

Comment: You can also utilise the [modes in which the servers run](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#modes), such as `staging` or `production` by creating files such as `.env.staging`, `.env.production` to map to the modes automaticaaly.